Framing bedroom closets in condo with concrete floors
I need to frame out a couple closets in a condo my mom just bought. Third floor unit. Previous owners 86'd the closets in favor of some really crappy Ikea wardrobes for some reason. They did a terrible job patching the walls where the framing was removed, too.
It's not a first floor unit but since it'll be on concrete I assume I'll still need to use one or both of (1) a sill plate gasket and/or (2) treated wood for the sill plates?
Do I need to still use treated wood if I use a sill plate gasket? My main concern is off-gassing since they're bedrooms. I'm not too concerned since it's a very small amount of wood.

Most closets/internal doors do not have sill plates.  The edge of the door frame goes straight up without anything on the floor.

Apologies if I mis-spoke, I mean the bottom plate of the framing for the closet walls - not below the doorway. I need to frame out one side and the front of each closet, since they removed the framing to expand the room size.

Shouldn't need treated or gasket if it isn't going to get wet...

Even if you want to be conservative w.r.t. the off-gassing, you can simply use a sill gasket (the pink foam strip) with untreated wood.
